# Redirect certain pages from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis-7, http-status-code-301, episerver

Google has indexed some of our pages with both HTTPS and HTTP.. I would like to redirect the ones that should not be HTTPS back to HTTP (301).

This is an EPiServer 7 site, but is MVC essentially.

I have the following in my controllers..

```
            if (currentPage.RequireSsl != null && currentPage.RequireSsl.Value && !HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            {
                return this.RedirectPermanent(HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
            }

        }
        else if (HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection && (currentPage.RequireSsl == null || currentPage.RequireSsl.Value == false))
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            {
                return this.RedirectPermanent(HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:"));
            }
        }
```

Now, it does what I want if a "secure" pages is requested non-https, it 301s to https (when viewed in fiddler).

```
**GET http://domainxx.com/section/securepage/
301 Moved Permanently to https://domainxx.com/section/securepage/**
```

However, if I request a non-secure page on HTTPS, it redirects, but I get a 200 status code, not 301. Fiddler doesn't even list the direct:

```
**GET http://domainxx/section/notsecurepage/
200 OK (text/html)**
```

Comment: OK, this is actually OK.. Fiddler isn't picking up HTTPS requests, but  http://www.howto301redirect.com/301-redirect-checker/ is, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new authorization filter as follows.

```
public class CustomRequireHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // abort if it's not a secure connection
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) return;

        // abort if a [RequireHttps] attribute is applied to controller or action
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;

        // abort if it's not a GET request - we don't want to be redirecting on a form post
        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return;

        // redirect to HTTP
        string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```

Then register it within the `FilterConfig` as follows

```
//redirect to http protocol if RequiredHttps not assigned to the requested action
filters.Add(new CustomRequireHttpsAttribute());
```

you will have to add `[RequireHttps]` to actions/controllers where you need `https` protocol

Comment: Not sure that's going to work in my case, as the Controller in question serves any number of URLS, based on the EPiServer page type.. I therefore can't add an attribute to my action...